# I want this table in LATEX. Kindly help

Tags: tables, tabularx

[image]

I want this table in LATEX. Kindly me with this. I make simple table but I'm unable to add more cells in a row. Shall be thankful to you.

Comment: Check the `multirow` package to have a 'row' span several actual rows.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  We'll be able to better help you if you post the ~20 lines you would need to create the simple version of the first few lines of the table.  That would give us something to work from.

Comment: Also, what problem are you having with your attempt?  Is it that one manufacturer should span several rows?  Or that your column headings should be narrower than they're turning out?  Or getting the checkmark?  Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

@Ch Qasim If the problem is just adding more lines, I prepared a preform for your table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[]
        \centering
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
                \hline
                Ref & Manufactures   & Models & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}DC \\ Motor \\ (Brushed)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}AC \\ Induction \\ Motor\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}DC \\ (Brushless) \\ Motor\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}PM-Sync \\ Reluctance \\ Motor \\ (IPMSynRM)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Permanent \\ Magnet-Sync. \\ Motor (PMSM)\end{tabular} \\ \hline
                & Toyota         &        &                                                                  &                                                                  &                                                                    &                                                                                      &                                                                                   \\ \hline
                & TESLA          &        &                                                                  &                                                                  &                                                                    &                                                                                      &                                                                                   \\ \hline
                & Nissan         &        &                                                                  &                                                                  &                                                                    &                                                                                      &                                                                                   \\ \hline
                & Porsche        &        &                                                                  &                                                                  &                                                                    &                                                                                      &                                                                                   \\ \hline
                & Audi           &        &                                                                  &                                                                  &                                                                    &                                                                                      &                                                                                   \\ \hline
                & BMW            &        &                                                                  &                                                                  &                                                                    &                                                                                      &                                                                                   \\ \hline
                & General Motors &        &                                                                  &                                                                  &                                                                    &                                                                                      &                                                                                   \\ \hline
                & Fiat Panda     &        &                                                                  &                                                                  &                                                                    &                                                                                      &                                                                                   \\ \hline
                & KIA            &        &                                                                  &                                                                  &                                                                    &                                                                                      &                                                                                   \\ \hline
                & Ather Energy   &        &                                                                  &                                                                  &                                                                    &                                                                                      &                                                                                   \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}%
        }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

If you need to add more rows, just use `& & & & & & & \\ \hline`

Also, for future tables, I found a online tool which could be useful for you [here](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/#).

[image]